# jQuery .on( click.class-name )

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm looking at the WordPress Google Analytics plugin, specifically the external link javascript file and I'm having trouble figuring out what this syntax means:

```
$('a:external').on( 'click.wp-google-analytics', function(e){
```

I see previously we defined a custom filter for external links but I'm talking about the `click.wp-google-analytics`. I didn't know a click could have a class name. Can anyone point me in the right direction of understanding this and why the class name is required?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a namespaced event. Provides a way to ensure you don't clobber existing events that might be attached by other users/plugins

http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events